# TypeScript: Define an Argument Representing a Type Which Implements an Abstract Class

Tags: typescript, types, interface, static, abstract

I have something akin to the following in TypeScript:

```
abstract class foo {
    public static bar: string;
}
class baz implements foo {
    public static bar: string = 'qux';
}
```

And would like to be able to do something like:

```
function quxx(t: Type<foo>) {
    console.log(t.bar);
}
quxx(baz); // should output "qux"
```

Without having to instantiate an instance of `baz`, but still being guaranteed to have the abstract class `foo` implemented on the passed type.  Does TypeScript support something like this?  `Type<foo>` is the piece here I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: There's quite a bit problematic about this example code, unfortunately.  First, `static` properties are, for whatever reason, not checked for initialization (see [ms/TS#27899](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27899)), so nothing will stop someone from doing [this](//tsplay.dev/N7gqRN) and messing you up; you need to treat all static properties as potentially `undefined`.  Second, `class X implements Y` when `Y` is a class name will only look at the instance side of `Y`, not the static side,  so nothing stops [this](//tsplay.dev/Nrv91N).

Comment: Third, `abstract` classes exist at runtime; you can't `new` them but you can use their static properties, so there's no reason you couldn't do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9J53m); there doesn't seem to be a principled reason why you would care about whether the class constructor is `abstract` or not if you are not going to try to construct an instance with it.  All of these together make me not sure how to proceed here...

Comment: If you want to access the `bar` property on something and have it be of type `string`, the type `{bar: string}` should suffice.  If you really care about a concrete constructor (but why?), you can make it `{ new (): Foo; bar: string }` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMR7ZW), but I do very much wish the example code here could be modified to actually motivate this.  As it stands I'm scratching my head...

Comment: @jcalz Honestly I'd prefer the `abstract class` be an `interface` but TypeScript doesn't appear to support `static` members in interfaces.  I absolutely don't want an instance for it.  My use case here is in trying to (as easily as possible) spread `GraphQL` schema across classes then compile it from a list of `types` instead of having to keep that information separate - doing `new baz(...)` for each of those would add on a ton of tech debt, vs just having a simple list of types `[ ..., baz, ...]` which can then have a `static` `_gqlschema` or similar member accessed.

Comment: @jcalz Ideally I'd be able to just call something like `appendGraphQL(t)` for each `type t` in such an array consisting of "everything I want to seemlessly surface in `GraphQL` without maintaining pages of boilerplate that aren't even all segregated by class."  My issue is in that I want to have `t` be strongly typed to the name of that `interface` or `abstract class` and not require an instance of the derived class be created for hundreds of different classes.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you're using `class`es at all for this if all you seem to care about are static properties.  Why not just drop down to an interface and objects assignable to it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wv813N)? Could you change your code to a [mcve] that motivates using classes at all?  If you need to bring GraphQL into it for it to make sense, maybe you should do that and tag the question with graphql so people who know about it can advise

Comment: @jcalz it needs to be a `static` property not an `instanced` property, I'd be fine with an interface, and prefer it semantically, but from what I've seen interfaces don't support `static` members within TypeScript.  In any event, I'm trying to strictly-type a `Type` passed, not an instance of a `Type`.  The minimal example is what I posted - the `t: Type<foo>` portion as a `quxx` argument is the one I'd like to mean "a `Type` which implements `foo`."

Comment: Right, interfaces don't support static properties. But since your example code doesn't use any instance properties, why use classes at all? If you only use the static side of a class, just use single objects. If you do need classes, please modify your code to some [mcve] that shows why. At this point I've exhausted the ways to approach the issue given the info I have. Presumably graphql is part of your use case, but I don't know graphql and your example doesn't use it. If you edit your code I'll come back and look. Otherwise, maybe someone else will be able to assist? Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz The example uses a `static` property - the classes would have non-static members, but need a specific `static` property to be included as well, which is why I'm using an `abstract class` as an `interface` for a `static` property to exist.  I want the `quxx` function to be strongly-typed to require that `static` property to exist.

Comment: As I said [here](//stackoverflow.com/questions/68841045/typescript-define-an-argument-representing-a-type-which-implements-an-abstract?noredirect=1#comment121662737_68841045), something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4p71W) is technically how you'd say "a concrete class constructor that has the static `bar` property".  That's the answer to your question as stated.  But there's no obvious motivation, and abstract static properties have pitfalls that make them a poor choice here. You say your classes would have non-static members; could you show that in your example code?

Comment: If you don't want to modify anything in the question, that's fine; it's your question, not mine.  But if so, I will probably just disengage since we are apparently at an impasse.

Comment: @jcalz apologies for forgetting to respond, the example you linked in the comment before your latest one was correct, I missed it on the first pass.  It got me through this issue so if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.  Thank you for helping.